# Apply multiple filters except Others in crossfilter dc js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a dimension on which user can filter with around 50 different values (by clicking on elements corresponding to each filter).

Showing all the fifty filters(elements) was not possible. 
So I am showing top 5 filter and have put rest in **Others** using the `chart.rowsCap(5)` method in dc.js.

User can select multiple filters, but it also allows the **Others** to be selected.

What I want is whenerver the **Others** is selected other filters should get removed and vice versa.

I tried several things but no luck so far.
Here is what I tried in the `on('filtered', func)` listener

```
chart.on('filtered', function(chart, filter){
    if(filter instanceof Array){
        if(chart.filters().indexOf("Others") !== -1) {
            chart.filter(null);
            chart.filter(filter);
        }
    } else if(filter == "Others") {
        if(chart.filters().indexOf("Others") !== -1 && chart.filters().length > 1){
            chart.filter(null);
            chart.filter(filter);
        }
    } else {
        if(chart.filters().indexOf("Others") !== -1){
        chart.filter(null);
        chart.filter(filter);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you want to use a listener for that; listeners are passive and late in the process.

Instead I think your best option is to control the behavior at the event level (although there are some proposals floating around to make the click filter behavior better configurable).

Try something like this:

```
var oc = chart.onClick;
chart.onClick = function(d) { chart.filter(null); oc.call(chart, d); }
```

This simply clears the filter before applying another one, so it defeats the toggling and gives you single-element selection. I'm not sure if that answers your whole question, but hopefully it should set you on your way.

EDIT: here is a more complicated onClick that makes Others mutually exclusive with the ordinary slices, but otherwise preserves the toggle.

```
chart.onClick = function (d) {
    var had_others = chart.filters().indexOf("Others")>=0;
    if(d.key === "Others") {
        chart.filter(null); 
        if(!had_others)
            oc.call(chart, d); 
        else chart.redrawGroup(); 
     } else { 
         if(had_others) chart.filter(null); 
         oc.call(chart, d); 
     } 
}
```

Comment: But, this way only one filter is applied not multiple. Only one filter should be applied only when the "Others" is selected, but with rest multiple selections should be allowed.
Also when I select (click on) the filter again it does not deselect it.

Comment: okay, i added code to make them unselect each other but otherwise do normal toggling.

Comment: Awesome. I wish I could voteup this answer thousand times.
Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! The code is more complicated than I'd like. [Would be awesome to have better primitives](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/716) to build these custom filter behaviors.